# Warning to use `.loc[]` when it is already being used

Tags: python, pandas

I am using `Pandas 0.24.2` to prepare some data for machine learning. To setup the data, I used the `StandardScaler()` in `scikit-learn` to normalize the features. However, I am getting this odd warning about

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

The odd thing is that I am already using the`.iloc[]` method on the dataframes. Here is the code itself below. Note that `x_train, x_test` are dataframes.

```
dat = pd.read_csv('/path/data.csv')
x_train, x_test = train_test_split(dat, 
                               test_size=0.2,
                               random_state=42)
scaler = StandardScaler()
x_train.iloc[:, :-1] = scaler.fit_transform(x_train.iloc[:, :-1])
x_test.iloc[:, :-1] = scaler.transform(x_test.iloc[:, :-1])

x_mean = scaler.mean_
x_std = scaler.scale_
```

Can anyone figure out what the actual problem is? I avoided rescaling the last column in the dataframe because it is the label column.

Comment: I am unable reproduce the issue. When I run the code example (using pandas 0.24.2) no warnings appear.

Comment: `x_train` and `x_test` were likely sliced improperly.

Comment: My guess is `x_train` and `x_test` are already a copies of a bigger dataset, say `train_df`. So really, you should/could do `train_df.loc[:, :-1] = scaler.fit_transform(x_train.loc[:, :-1])`

Comment: @QuangHoang sorry, let me add some additional code. I created `x_train,`x_test` from the `train_test_split` function.

Comment: @QuangHoang So `x_train, x_test` came from a larger dataset that I split into 2 chunks. I tried using just `.loc`, but that generated a different error `TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [-1] of <class 'int'>`

Comment: Try instead: `scaler.fit(x_train.iloc[:, :-1])` then `dat.iloc[:, :-1] = scaler.transform(dat.iloc[:,:-1])` should transform both `x_train` and `x_test`.

Comment: @QuangHoang Yes this worked. Thanks for the idea. I think the problem has something to do with the indexing that comes out of the `train_test_split()` function. I wonder if reindexing might also solve the problem. But your idea did fix it.

Comment: Nope, rescaling did not work. This could just be a false positive warning and I can ignore it. Oh well. But thanks to everyone for their help.

Comment: @QuangHoang actually I realized that we should not run `scaler` on the original full `dat` data. In principle, we want to fit the scaler to the training data only--since we don't know the test data at training time. If we fit to the full `dat` data, this scaling is different than just scaling on the `x_train` data and then applying that scaling to the `x_test`. Subtle but important point, but even if the code works does not mean you should follow it. Haha :).

Comment: Please read my comment again. Yes, `fit` on the `x_train` and `transform` the whole dataset.

Comment: Oh yes, I see that now. Haha. So you were ahead of the curve :). Good catch.